# Index is out of bounds for axis 0 with size - python

Tags: python, deep-learning, scnnode

I have 72 image to classify with my model and now I'm trying to make a prediction with my classification, but I have encountered an error about 
index 32 that is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 32.

```
test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
img_batch = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(images_dir, target_size=
test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
img_batch = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(images_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height), shuffle=False)
predictions = model.predict_generator(img_batch, steps=1)
filenames = img_batch.filenames
predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions,axis=1)
classnames = []
print(len(classnames))
for i in range(72):
    classnames.append(class_names[predicted_class_indices.item(i)])
results = pd.DataFrame({"Filename":filenames,
                      "Prediction":classnames})
results.head(72)
```

And I am getting some error like this:

```
Found 72 images belonging to 3 classes.
0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-1d228169f5c1> in <module>
      9 print(len(classnames))
     10 for i in range(72):
---> 11     classnames.append(class_names[predicted_class_indices.item(i)])
     12 results = pd.DataFrame({"Filename":filenames,
     13                       "Prediction":classnames})

IndexError: index 32 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 32
```

Comment: In brief, `predicted_class_indices` has only 32 items, not 72.

Comment: As the error is already stating, index 32 does not exist in `predicted_class_indices` which has a size of 32. Why it only has a size of 32 and not the 72 you are expecting, I don't know (as the code that calculates that is not included).

Comment: What is `class_names`? How long is `class_names`? I'm guessing that `class_names` is length 32, and `predicted_class_indices.item(i)` returns 32 for some value of `i`. But you're not showing the value of `i`, nor what `class_names` is, so we don't know.

Comment: `class_names` contains label about my class, and i have 3 clases. and `predicted_class_indices` has only 32 items, eventhought in `flow_from_directory` found 72 images.